# How can I loop through values in my json file?

Tags: json, angularjs, protractor

suppose I have a json file and I would like to loop through the values like so:

```
var myModel = {"id": 0, "date": "2014-10-28", "amount": 1111, "productId": "2", "description": "Cash"};

for (value in myModel) 
    {
      //element(by.model(key)).clear().sendKeys(value);
    }
```

This is a part of a **jasmine script** but it is not the point. The question is how can I loop through my model per key i.e **'id','date'** etc and their values in angular js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need this:

```
  for (key in myModel) {
      console.log("key is :",key)
      console.log("value is:",myModel[key])
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular [foreach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) will do the trick

> Invokes the iterator function once for each item in obj collection,
>   which can be either an object or an array. The iterator function is
>   invoked with iterator(value, key, obj), where value is the value of an
>   object property or an array element, key is the object property key or
>   array element index and obj is the obj itself. Specifying a context
>   for the function is optional.

```
    var values = {"id": 0, "date": "2014-10-28", "amount": 1111, "productId": "2",
                  "description": "Cash"};
        var log = [];
        angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
          this.push(key + ': ' + value);
        }, log);
        console.log(log);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p11ejmgq/)**